# Angular.js view doesn't update when nested $scope array is updated

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-scope, angularjs-ng-repeat

I am trying to make an angular.js view update itself when adding a comment. My code is as follows:

```
<div class="comment clearfix" data-ng-repeat="comment in currentItem.comments" data-ng-class="{bubble: $first}" data-ng-instant>
    <div>
        <p>
            <span class="username">{{comment.user}}</span> {{comment.message}}
        </p>
        <p class="time">
            10 minutes ago
        </p>
    </div>
</div>
<div class="comment reply">
    <div class="row-fluid">
        <div class="span1">
            <img src="assets/img/samples/user2.jpg" alt="user2" />
        </div>
        <div class="span11">
            <textarea class="input-block-level addComment" type="text" placeholder="Reply…"></textarea>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

the scope is updated on enter:

```
$('.addComment').keypress(function(e) {
    if(e.which == 10 || e.which == 13) {
        $scope.currentItem.comments.push({
            "user": "user3",
            "message": $(this).val()
        });
        console.debug("currentItem", $scope.currentItem);
    }
});
```

debugging $scope.currentItem shows that the comment has been added to it, however the view doesn't show the new comment. I suspect that the $scope is only being watched on its first level and that this is why the view doesn't update. is that the case? If so how can I fix it?

SOLUTION:
As Ajay suggested in his answer below I wrapped the array push into the apply function like this:

```
var el=$(this);
$scope.$apply(function () {
     $scope.currentChallenge.comments.push({
         "user": $scope.currentUser,
         "message": el.val()
     });
});
```

Comment: check if the css applied for the new comment added is causing it to move away from the viewable screen

Comment: thanks for the suggestion, but this is not the case, I had a look at the html in firebug and the new comment clearly hasn't been added.

Comment: but in your question you said while debugging u found that comment was added .what do you mean by that ?

Comment: wrap the calling inside $scope.apply() then it will work

Comment: Thanks Ajay, I gave that a try and it works like a charm! Thanks so much! If you fancy putting that into an answer and explain it a bit I can accept your answer.

Comment: dreamweiver, I meant that I debugged "$scope.currentItem" in the controller and the new message was in there after pressing enter, but it hadn't been added into the html view.

Comment: @dine when I do this :: $scope.$apply(function () {
                                       $scope.Images.push(data);
                                   });   "Error: [$rootScope:inprog] $digest already in progress" Is coming if i remove the apply() then same problem occurs as mention in the question.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Modify the code to wrap inside scope.$apply because you are modifying  the property outside the angular scope you have to use [scope.$apply()](http://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng.%24rootScope.Scope#%24apply) to watch the values

Comment: when I do this :: $scope.$apply(function () {
                                       $scope.Images.push(data);
                                   });   "Error: [$rootScope:inprog] $digest already in progress" Is coming if i remove the apply() then same problem occurs as mention in the question.

Comment: I think in your case it would be something like: $scope.Images.push(data); $scope.$apply(); ...

Answer (score 0):

I had to place my form inside the same div controller as the ng-repeat. I had two separate div controllers.

Answer (score 0):

Use $scope.$parent.arrayObjet to modify the parent variables instead of $scope.arryaObject.  It worked in my case.

Answer (score 0):

```
<div class="col-sm-12 col-lg-12">
            <div class="outer-container">
                <div class="inner-container">
                    <div class="table-header">
                        <form id="teamForm" name="teamForm">
                            <table class="table table-bordered">
                                <thead>

                                <!-- Grid header -->
                                <tbody data-ng-if="(allTeamMembers.length==0)">
                                    <tr>
                                        <td class="text-center height_33_p" colspan="15"> {{noResultFound}} </td>
                                    </tr>
                                </tbody>
                                <!-- Existing team member -->

                                <tbody data-ng-repeat="tm in teammemberDetailsArryobject|orderBy:orderByField:reverseSort" data-ng-form="innerForm_$index" data-ng-class="{'ng-submitted':innerForm_$index.$submitted}">
                                    <tr></tr>
                                    </tbody>
```

In the code I am deleting one record and add new row programmatically but all the rows are displayed in the ng-repeat rows(including deleted)

Comment: This is what's happening to me, too.  Did you ever find a solution?