# AngularJS: nested array and view update

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-scope

I'm having problems updating the view after an `Array` inside an `Array` is updated in the `$scope`.

First i check if the Array member already exists:

```
$scope.myArray = [];
if(typeof $scope.myArray[someIndex] == 'undefined') {
  $scope.myArray[someIndex] = {
    name: someName,
    data: []
  };
}
```

Then push to `$scope.myArray[someIndex].data`:

```
$scope.myArray[someIndex].data.push(dataContent);
```

At this point the view does not update.

Of course if i directly push to `$scope.myArray` it does. Any suggestions?

Edit: Fiddle [here](http://jsfiddle.net/cRzr2/3/)

Comment: Have you tried calling `$scope.$apply()` afterwards? What happens then?

Comment: I did, tried the solution in http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16039076/angular-js-view-doesnt-update-when-nested-scope-array-is-updated, but i get "$digest already in progress error"

Comment: Can you set up a fiddle that shows the problem?

Comment: Sure, updated with the fiddle

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It was simpler than it looked.

Based on the response [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8630479/999516) i am setting an associative array which allows set string keys. If you declare your array as `=[]` you simply cannot set strings as keys.

So i just changed my declaration `$scope.myArray=[]` to `$scope.myArray={}` and voilà, it works.

Comment: lol, in your example you used `someIndex` which didn't imply it as being a string, If I knew that I could have told you from the start that a plain object works as a dictionary.

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
if(typeof $scope.myArray[someIndex] == 'undefined') {
   $scope.$eval(function(){
     $scope.myArray[someIndex] = {
       name: someName,
       data: []
     };
     $scope.myArray[someIndex].data.push(dataContent);
   });       
}
```

Comment: Tried but with no luck.

Answer (score 0):

This works:

HTML,

```
<div ng-app>
    <div ng-controller="NestedCtrl">
        <article ng-repeat="member in myArray">
            {{member.name}}
            <article ng-repeat="next in member.data">
                {{next.nested}}
            </article>
        </article>
    </div>
</div>
```

Angular JS:

```
function NestedCtrl($scope) {

    $scope.myArray = [];

    var callMe = function(){
      if(typeof $scope.myArray[0] == 'undefined') {
          $scope.myArray[0] = {
              name: 'Hello',
              data: []
          };
      }

      $scope.myArray[0].data.push({nested : 'yay'});   
    }

    callMe();
}
```